# Why scala cannot resolve the T parameter

Tags: scala, generics

When I try to call the following function:

```
def sortBy[T, R](seq: Seq[T], by: T => R)(implicit ordering: Ordering[R]): Seq[T] = {
    ...
}
```

with this:

```
case class MyClass(f1: Int, f2: Int)
val o1 = MyClass(1, 2)
val o2 = MyClass(3, 4)

sortBy(Seq(o1, o2), x => x.f1)
```

I get compilation error "cannot resolve symbol f1"

However when I call it with explicit types it works:

```
sortBy[MyClass,Int](...)
```

My question is why scala cannot infer these types automatically?

Comment: Is this even Scala code ? What is `case class MyClass(Int f1, Int f2)` ? Do you think this will compile ?

Comment: Yes, it's a scala code, I had a mistake when I copied it from my code repository to here. I'll edit the question. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: The problem is that in **Scala 2** type inference looks at all arguments of the same parameter group. So it is unable to infer the argument of the function. Split those into two parameters groups and it will work as expected. - Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69489355/whats-the-purpose-of-currying-given-other-alternatives-to-return-a-function-in/69489428#69489428

Comment: Thank you @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez! It solved the error

Answer (score 0):

As one of the ways to solve

```scala
def sortBy[T, R](seq: Seq[T], by: T => R)(implicit ordering: Ordering[R]): Seq[T] = ???

case class MyClass(f1: Int, f2: Int)
val o1 = MyClass(1, 2)
val o2 = MyClass(3, 4)

def orderFunc(a: MyClass): Int = a.f1

sortBy(Seq(o1, o2), orderFunc)
```

Comment: This is more complicated that the solution given in the question (`sortBy[MyClass,Int](...)`)